# Saving arrays of custom class objects

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if there was an easy way to save arrays of objects, without having to go through and save each aspect of the the objects.  In my example I have two arrays, one a single array and the other a 2D array, that contain objects referring to a custom class.  Each object has specific details like x and y ints, booleans, strings, ect. attached to them (block[0].x, block[0].canWalk, block[0].name) and I was wondering if there is an easy way of saving these arrays to a file without having to use a for loop and save each part.  The multidimensional array is simply an array of saved arrays identical to the first one (savedBlock[0][0].x ...)

What I have so far (throwing NotSerializableException):

```
public class Save
{
    static File f;
    static ObjectOutputStream os;
    public static void openFile()
    {
        try
        {
            if(!new File("c:\\IDsGame").exists())
            {
                new File("c:\\IDsGame").mkdirs();
            }

            f = new File("c:\\IDsGame\\data.bin");
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));

            writeFile();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("creating file");
        }
    }

    public static void writeFile()
    {
        try
        {
            ArrayList<Object> map = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(Map.block));
            ArrayList<Object> savedMaps = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(Map.savedMaps));
            os.writeObject(map);
            os.writeObject(savedMaps);
            os.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}

    }
}
```

Within my map class I initialize block (Blocks[]) and savedMaps(Blocks[][]).  My Blocks class holds this:

```
public class Blocks implements Serializable
{
    public boolean canWalk, onTop, itemTaken;
    public Image img = null, imgBack = null;
    public final Image (a ton of different images)
    public String name, item, message, title;
    public char initMap, initEx, initIt;
    public int x, y, height, width;

    public Blocks()
    {
        canWalk = true;
        onTop = false;
        itemTaken = false;
        img = null;
        name = null;
        item = null;
        message = null;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        height = 0;
        width = 0;
    }
}
```

Obviously I change the certain parts different arrays within the Map class, and I was wondering if there was any easier way (at all) to save the arrays of Blocks Objects.

Thanks for taking your time to help and if you need any more specific just let me know.

I.D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image is not serializable, so you receive a NotSerializableException when the Blocks class is serialized.  ImageIcon can be serialized, so wrapping Image instances in ImageIcons will solve that issue.

```
public class Blocks implements Serializable
{
    public boolean canWalk, onTop, itemTaken;
    public ImageIcon img = null, imgBack = null;
    public final ImageIcon (a ton of different images)
    public String name, item, message, title;
    public char initMap, initEx, initIt;
    public int x, y, height, width;

    public Blocks()
    {
        canWalk = true;
        onTop = false;
        itemTaken = false;
        img = null;
        // img = new ImageIcon(someImageInstance)
        name = null;
        item = null;
        message = null;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        height = 0;
        width = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That throws the same "NotSerializableException"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you have a serializable class, and array of objects of that class are serializable as well.  Make sure you're using the correct Blocks object.  Alternatively, you could override writeObject and readObject in your Blocks class to add the fields to an array to be serialized.

Comment: @Vulcan You are correct (and I tested it to make sure): Arrays are serializable, as long as all their elements are serializable.

Comment: Do you know if all the elements within the Blocks class are serializable?

Comment: I will try using ImageIcons instead of Images (which aren't seriablizable)

Comment: ImageIcon fixed the problem.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: -1 For "editing" (ie changing) your answer to the essence of my unedited correct answer 6 minutes after I posted (that is called plagiarism). Your original answer was incorrect. BTW, this is the first time I have ever downvoted for this reason; I did so because in this case the plagiarism was so blatant I wanted to make a point in the hope you won't do it again. Editing is supposed to be for "minor" improvements. You really should had *deleted* this answer and posted a new answer.

Comment: I honestly didn't see your answer, and I rather wrote up a test case of serializing an array of Blocks before encountering the same exception and did some research on array serialization (googling "java serializable array custom class").  Then, I checked that everything was serializable (I thought Image was prior to checking), and upon finding Image wasn't, researched it, and learned about wrapping in ImageIcons.

Answer (score 0):

Just making a class implement `Serializable` is not enough: All the fields must be `Serializable` too.

Your `Block` class may have a problem. All the usual java classes are `Serializable`, but `Block` also has fields of type `Image`. If `Image` isn't `Serializable`, then attempting to serialize `Block` will throw `NotSerializableException`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try changing them to ImageIcons (which I am pretty sure are serializable) and see where that takes me.